# How to return 0 if cell value is 0 or value from different cell if cell is empty

Tags: vba, excel

I used macro from http://www.erlandsendata.no/english/index.php?d=envbawbreadfromclosedwb.
I would like to check if cell B1 contains any value or 0 and return this value or, if cell B1 is empty, return value from cell A1.

```
Sub ReadDataFromAllWorkbooksInFolder()
Dim FolderName As String, wbName As String, r As Long, cValue As Variant
Dim wbList() As String, wbCount As Integer, i As Integer
FolderName = "C:\check"
' create list of workbooks in foldername
wbCount = 0
wbName = Dir(FolderName & "\" & "*.xls")
While wbName <> vbNullString
    wbCount = wbCount + 1
    ReDim Preserve wbList(1 To wbCount)
    wbList(wbCount) = wbName
    wbName = Dir
Wend
If wbCount = 0 Then Exit Sub
' get values from each workbook
r = 0
Workbooks.Add
For i = 1 To wbCount
    r = r + 1
    cValue = GetInfoFromClosedFile(FolderName, wbList(i), "Sheet1", "B1")
    If Not IsEmpty(cValue) Then
    Cells(r, 1).Formula = cValue
    Else
    cValue = GetInfoFromClosedFile(FolderName, wbList(i), "Sheet1", "A1")
    Cells(r, 1).Formula = cValue
    End If
    Next i
 End Sub

Private Function GetInfoFromClosedFile(ByVal wbPath As String, wbName As String, wsName As String, cellRef As String) As Variant
Dim arg As Variant
GetInfoFromClosedFile = Empty
If Right(wbPath, 1) <> "\" Then wbPath = wbPath & "\"
If Dir(wbPath & wbName) = vbNullString Then Exit Function
arg = "'" & wbPath & "[" & wbName & "]" & wsName & "'!" & Range(cellRef).Address(True, True, xlR1C1)
On Error Resume Next
GetInfoFromClosedFile = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)
End Function
```

It works when B1 contains any value or 0, but when B1 is empty it still returns 0 and not value from cell A1, e.g.:
If value in B1 = 34, it returns 34.
If value in B1 = 0, it returns 0.
If B1 is empty, it returns 0 – in that case I would like to get value from cell A1.
What should I change to get desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Borrowing heavily from this [Mr Excel](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/600597-pull-function-empty-cells.html) thread

```
Sub ReadDataFromAllWorkbooksInFolder()
Dim FolderName As String, wbName As String, r As Long, cValue As Variant
Dim wbList() As String, wbCount As Integer, i As Integer
FolderName = "C:\test"
' create list of workbooks in foldername
wbCount = 0
wbName = Dir(FolderName & "\" & "*.xls")
While wbName <> vbNullString
    wbCount = wbCount + 1
    ReDim Preserve wbList(1 To wbCount)
    wbList(wbCount) = wbName
    wbName = Dir
Wend
If wbCount = 0 Then Exit Sub
' get values from each workbook
r = 0
Workbooks.Add
For i = 1 To wbCount
    r = r + 1
        cValue = GetInfoFromClosedFile(FolderName, wbList(i), "Sheet1", "B1")
        If cValue = "X" Then cValue = GetInfoFromClosedFile(FolderName, wbList(i), "Sheet1", "A1")
        Cells(r, 1).Formula = cValue
Next i
End Sub
```

*pull function*

```
Private Function GetInfoFromClosedFile(ByVal wbPath As String, wbName As String, wsName As String, cellRef As String) As Variant
Dim arg As Variant
GetInfoFromClosedFile = Empty
If Right(wbPath, 1) <> "\" Then wbPath = wbPath & "\"
If Dir(wbPath & wbName) = vbNullString Then Exit Function
arg = "'" & wbPath & "[" & wbName & "]" & wsName & "'!" & Range(cellRef).Address(True, True, xlR1C1)
On Error Resume Next
GetInfoFromClosedFile = ExecuteExcel4Macro("IF(COUNTA(" & arg & ")," & arg & ",""X"")")
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, brettdj, that's it!  I also tried solutions suggested by psychicebola and Excel, but I couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this part in your `GetInfoFromClosedFile` function

```
If Range(Cellref).value = "" Then
    arg = "'" & wbPath & "[" & wbName & "]" & wsName & "'!" & Range("A1").Address(True, True, xlR1C1)
else
    arg = "'" & wbPath & "[" & wbName & "]" & wsName & "'!" & Range(cellRef).Address(True, True, xlR1C1)
End if
```

And you can skip the If condition in your for-loop